# Get the smallest element in a specific row or column in a 2nd array

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm wondering how might to get the smallest element in a specific row of a 2nd array in java.

I have tried arrays.sort but it doesn't work like expected.

this is what I have :

```
static int largestinrow(int[][] arr, int row){
    int nums = arrays.sort(arr[row]);
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Why you removed the code you share before? I would suggest to rollback your question!

Comment: how can i roll back a question?

Comment: click on __'edited ... ago'__ and then on __'rollback'__ on the version you want to rollback to.

Comment: I do it for you, next time you can try it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) and [`IntStream.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#min--):

```
static int smallestinrow(int[][] arr, int row){
    return Arrays.stream(arr[row])
            .min()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

To get the smallest number in the whole 2d array you can use:

```
static int smallest(int[][] arr){
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
            .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
            .min()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

If you want to return a default value for an empty array, instead of throwing an exception you can use `.orElse()` instead of `.orElseThrow()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
static int smallestinrow(int[][] arr, int row) {
    Arrays.sort(arr[row]); // sort the array with the specific index(row)
    return arr[row][0];    // get the first value of the specific array
}
```

---

**Example :**

```
int[][] arr = {{1, 2, 22, 3, 0}, {1, 2, 33, -1, 66}};
System.out.println(smallestinrow(arr, 1));
=> -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initial question was to find the smallest number.
If you are using Java 7 and want minimal change to your code then you can use this.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = new int[][]{{1, 0}, {1, 4}};
    System.out.println(smallestinrow(a, 0)[0]);
  }

  static int[] smallestinrow(int[][] arr, int row) {
    Arrays.sort(arr[row]);
    return arr[0];//first element after ordering in ascending
  }
}
```